# Dualboot Pop!_os and win10 on two separate drives in a secure way

Tags: windows, dual-boot, ssd, pop-os

I want to use linux as my everyday os, I just need windows occasionally because I use an oculus rift and support isn´t great on linux yet.

I have a SSD and a HDD on my laptop and I want to install Linux on the SSD and Win10 on the HDD. I just want to be sure Windows doesn´t mess or break my linux system while updating or something similar; is there anything in particular I should do or be careful about?

Answer (score 0):

Windows will not mess with your Linux drive. Windows does not support Linux files or file systems. [See here](https://superuser.com/questions/403805/why-does-windows-not-recognize-files-inside-linux-partitions/403812) for information on why.

Comment: Windows has record of royally messing up GRUB after updates. It is lesser an issue with UEFI though.

Comment: I didn't know that, @AbdullahIbnFulan, thanks for sharing. I had thought Windows couldn't even see a Linux partition.

Comment: I didn´t know that either! thanks! and also, thank you hjpoe!

Comment: Yes, it cannot see, but in a BIOS scheme, it used to overwrite the leading MBR sectors (boot sectors), which pointed to GRUB, with Windows bootloader. So you cannot boot into GRUB without grub-repair. Now UEFI system is intelligent enough to boot any number of OS from EFI present in first 2 TB.